# RTL Beamer: getting lists to right-align

Tags: beamer, itemize, right-to-left

This code produces a list of items aligned to the left margin. In a proper RTL text they should be right-aligned. `\raggedright` doesn't have the expected effect. From other posts I suspect that `\setbeamertemplate` and `\setRTL` will be involved in the solution.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=eastern]{farsi}
\newfontfamily\farsifont[Script=arab]{Adobe Arabic}
\newfontfamily\farsifontsf[Script=arab]{Adobe Arabic}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{سیب}
%   \raggedright
\begin{itemize}
\item سیب سیب سیب سیب
\item سیب سیب
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you wanted to use `\raggedleft` and not `\raggedright`. Also it has to be issued inside `itemize` and not outside it.

MWE (I've used `Amiri` since I don't have `Adobe Arabic` installed):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=eastern]{farsi}
\newfontfamily\farsifont[Script=arab]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\farsifontsf[Script=arab]{Amiri}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{سیب}
\begin{itemize}\raggedleft
\item سیب سیب سیب سیب
\item سیب سیب
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had tried `\raggedleft` before, but not within the itemize environment.

Comment: @adam.baker you're welcome